# Wget Linux command is downloading files with Read Permissions for only sudo users - how to give Read permissions to all users?

Tags: php, ubuntu, permissions, wget, shell-exec

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 and I am programming in PHP. Here is my problem:

I have a need to use the **`wget`** linux command to download all files from a website. So I am using PHP's **`shell_exec()`** function to execute the command:

```
$wgetCommand = "wget  --recursive  --page-requisites  --convert-links  $url  2>&1";
$wgetCommandOutput = shell_exec($wgetCommand);
```

This command downloads all files and folders from a website, recursively, to the current working directory (unless otherwise specified). The problem is that when these files and folders are downloaded, I do not have permissions to read them programmatically  after that.

But if I do something like **`sudo chmod 777 -R path/to/downloaded/website/directory`** after they are downloaded with the `wget` command and before they are read programmatically, they are read just fine and everything works.

So I need a way to download folders and files from a website using **`wget`** command and they should have read permissions for *all* users, not just `sudo`.
How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a umask issue with the user running the PHP script.

Normally, Ubuntu would have a default umask of 0002. This would create a file with (-rw-rw-r--).

From the console you can check and set the umask for the PHP user via:

```
$umask
```

And inside the PHP script, do a

```
<?php
    umask()
```

If you are on a running webserver, it would, however be better to alter the files permissions of the downloaded files afterwards, via

```
<?php
    chmod()
```

The reason is, that the umask handles file creation for all files - not just your script.